# msal HTTP_INTERCEPTORS not adding with Request header automatically

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement MSAL authentication in angular application. So when application starting its login correctly using Azure AD.

Also I am using msal_interceptor as provider in app.module

```
 providers: [
  LoaderService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true
  },
  { 
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true 
  }
]
```

So I tried to call a test API like this

```
return this.client.get(url+'weatherforecast', {
  responseType: 'json'
});
```

API is returning correctly since its not an Authorization enabled API. I checked the Request header in chrome. But there is no token header anywhere mentioned. So whats wrong I did

This is the Request I copied from Chrome

```
curl "https://localhost:44331/weatherforecast" ^
  -H "authority: localhost:44331" ^
  -H "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" ^
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "origin: http://localhost:4200" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" ^
  -H "referer: http://localhost:4200/" ^
  -H "accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" ^
  --compressed
```

Comment: curl doesn't add Authorization header. You should check chrome network tab

Answer (score 0):

You must add the protected resource in a Map and pass it to MsalInterceptorConfiguration using protectedResourceMap attribute. please see the example below

```
function msalInterceptorConfigFactory (): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const myProtectedResourcesMap = new Map<string, Array<string | ProtectedResourceScopes> | null>();
    myProtectedResourcesMap.set(protectedResource, ['openid', 'profile', environment.msalConfig.clientId]);
    myProtectedResourcesMap.set(protectedResource, ['openid', 'profile', environment.msalConfig.clientId]);

    return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap: myProtectedResourcesMap,
        authRequest: { state: 'qwerty' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare your api routes and scopes required using [protectedResources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular#cors-api-usage).

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_eFO3LUHAaA4mmNL&Q_CHL=gl
>

Comment: @Alfredo R the provided link is out of date - the docs link to #cors-api-usage doesn't work and it's not clear how/where to "declare your api routes and scopes" or what "protectedResources" are. Can you provide updated information?